# Не получается создать табуляцию в коде на Python

Tags: python, синтаксис

Решил написать код, выводящий таблицу умножения промежутков чисел, вводимых пользователем. но на этапе начала столкнулся с проблемой: '/t' и '/n' не работают - не выводится ни пробела, ни отступа, ни переноса данных на новую строку, выводятся как обычные стринговые символы. С самим форматом отступа я пытался играться как мог: "/ t", " /t ", " / t " - ничего не помогло. Аналогично и с "/n".

```
print("*", "/t", "5")
Вывод: * /t 5

print("*", "/n", "5")
Вывод: * /n 5
```

Я работаю на Python 3.10, прога PyCharm. посерфив Интернет примерно полчаса не нашел ничего. Может дело в компиляторе? Обновить сам Python или PyCharm? Загрузить библиотеку?
Подскажите, что мне нужно делать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы используете прямой слэш `/`, а необходимо обратный `\`.

```
print("*", "\t", "5")
print("*", "\n", "5")
```

Вывод:

```
*    5
* 
 5
```